# My own module not transpiled correctly when imported from node_modules

Tags: webpack, import, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I published a simple plugin to npm which I wrote in ES6 and transpiled it using Webpack and Babel. Later I used this plugin in another ES6 project.

I am using a simple import statement:

```
import myplugin from 'myplugin';
```

The import is successful but it is not getting transpiled in the final output. I see the actual ES6 code in my output js file. Can anyone point to what could be the reason behind it?

The plugin code is getting transpiled directly in its own project.

Comment: if you have `.babelrc` in package folder, it will override setting of your project

Comment: but I have same settings in package as well as in my project

Comment: it was my first guess, it hard to help w/out working demo, that will shows failing build

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much information about your `webpack.config.js` but I would suggest using `include` instead of `exclude` under your babel loader rules

```
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.js$/,
            include: [
                path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
                path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/myplugin'),
            ],
            use: {
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                query: {
                    presets: ['env']
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, that works! However, my approach for was wrong actually. We aren't suppose to compile node_modules. What I did was I changed my webpack configuration, re-compiled my code as a library (umd), and changed the main file in package.json to point to compiled code rather than source code and it worked. But thanks anyways! :)